# const global string literal corrupted

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a const string literal that is getting corrupted.

What is strange is that it is apparently behaving differently depending upon the version of XCode that is installed (I've got to do a few more experiments before I can 100% confirm this), but even if its not Xcode then I'm wondering what the cause could be.

If the exact same code is run on the exact same handset but with one run its connected to a laptop running Xcode 3.3.3 then this problem is manifesting, if the same code and same handset is run with a different laptop with XCode 4.3.2 or 4.4 installed then the problem does not manifest.

The issues is this:

```
HeaderFile.h
extern NSString* const kValue;

HeaderFile.m
NSString* const kValue = @"Some Value";

OtherFile.m
#import "HeaderFile.h"
...
NSLog(@"Value is: %@", kValue);
```

When connected to the laptop with Xcode 4.3.3 then the value logged or observed when debugging for the global constant is corrupt.

Any ideas how this could be?

As its a const literal it should not be possible for it to be scribbled over if there is a bug in my code.

UPDATE:
I examined the value of kValue immediately after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: gets called and its already corrupted at that point, so there's no opportunity for my code to scribble on it, even if it is scribable.

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354423/explanation-of-constants

Comment: It's very possible that the initializer of your constant never gets called, due to some loader quirk (or due to simply failing to include HeaderFile.m in your app).

Answer (score 1):

*As its a const literal it should not be possible for it to be scribbled over if there is a bug in my code.*

That is not completely true.

First of all, const can even be removed by a simple cast. Second if you have a serous bug you could be writing to the memory that stores a variable because you are accessing beyond the memory of another variable (for example if you take the address of a `short` and cast it to be of type `long*` then access it). Third you have the pointer itself declared const, but the data pointed to is not const (at least not according to the declaration).

On the other hand, in general, it's true that what you observe could be impossible. Often globals declared const are put in a memory area that is read only at runtime. But not all hardware allows this and there's no real requirement on compilers that this be done. Also string literals are, in general, also to be considered const, meaning that in fact what you point to may also be stored in a const area (even if the pointer is not const).

I have no idea why you observe that behavior and I do not know the internals of the compiler and of the iPhone hardware, so I cannot say whether it is actually impossible to modify that data because of a bug. But I know that by language rules it is perfectly legal for the compiler (and the hardware) to store everything in a modifiable area. And if that's what they do, then yes, a bug may be the problem.

Comment: I examined the value of kValue immediately after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: gets called and its already corrupted at that point, so there's no opportunity for my code to scribble on it, even if it is scrubbable. Any ideas what I could do to try to get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Is it corrupted even earlier than that? What is it when `main` enters?

Comment: There too. I cannot reproduce this on another laptop with an identical set up, so I'm leaning towards thinking there's something screwy with the Xcode installation (it wouldn't be the first time) rather than something intrinsically wrong with the code. So I'm going to uninstall/reinstall and see what the outcome it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I agree that may be the case. It's theoretically possible to check what happens even earlier, but it's not worth the effort as it's unlikely to be due to code. Just make sure it **is** corrupted, not just reported as such (try an NSLog and compare to what the debugger says).